# Is there a not (!) operator in regexp?

Tags: java, regex

I need to remove all characters from the given string except for several which should left. How to do that with regexp?

Simple test: characters[1, a, *] shouldn't be removed, all other should from string "asdf123**".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is: ^ in a set.

You should be able to do something like:

```
text = text.replaceAll("[^1a*]", "");
```

Full sample:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String input = "asdf123**";
        String output = input.replaceAll("[^1a*]", "");
        System.out.println(output); // Prints a1**
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to escape the `*` in a character class.

Comment: You also don't need to escape a hyphen if it's at the end or the beginning of a character class. So [^*.-] represents everything that's not an asterisk, a period, or a hyphen. :)

Comment: Thanks! I was confused a little that the same sign is used to match the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 13):

When used inside `[` and `]` the `^` (caret) is the `not` operator.

It is used like this:

```
"[^abc]"
```

That will match any character except for `a` `b` or `c`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a negated [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html), which might work for this instance. You define one by putting `^` at the beginning of the class, such as:

`[^1a\*]`

for your specific case.

Comment: you ned to escape the *, should be \\*

Comment: Actually you don't (in regex dialects that I'm aware of, anyway), but you can. I'll add it to be explicit, though.

Comment: @Cfreak: no you don't (see above)

Answer (score 0):

In a character class the ^ is not. So

`[^1a\*]` would match all characters except those.

Answer (score 0):

You want to match against all characters except: [asdf123*], use ^

Answer (score 0):

There's no "not" operator in Java regular expressions like there is in Perl.

Comment: Are you talking about Perl's inverted regex match operator `!~`?  That's not really relevant, given that the OP is doing a substitution, not a match.  And if he *were* trying to match the characters rather than replace them, he would need to do a *positive* match for a regex that excludes those characters, as the other responders pointed out.  For example, in Perl he might do this: `my @result = $s =~ m/[^1a*]+/g;`